# Boundedness of certain polynomial over complex field

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$ where $|a| \le 1$. Given the polynomial
\begin{align*}
P(z) = \frac{a}{2} + (1-|a|^2)z - \frac{\overline{a}}{2}z^2
\end{align*}
Prove that $|P(z)| \le 1$ if $|z| \le 1$.

Comment: Try computing $P(z)\overline{P(z)}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I'm trying to use Schwarz Lemma, but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

By maximum modulus principle, we can suppose that $|z|=1$, or $z=e^{i\beta}$. Let $a=re^{i\alpha}$, with $0\leq r\leq1$.

Then, 
$$P(z)=-\frac{re^{i(2\beta-\alpha)}}2+(1-r^2)e^{i\beta}+\frac{re^{i\alpha}}2$$
$$\Re P(z)=-\frac r2\cos(2\beta-\alpha)+(1-r^2)\cos\beta+\frac r2\cos\alpha$$
$$\Im P(z)=-\frac r2\sin(2\beta-\alpha)+(1-r^2)\sin\beta+\frac r2\sin\alpha$$
$$\begin{align}
|P(z)|^2&=\frac{r^2}4+(1-r^2)^2+\frac{r^2}4\\
&\qquad-r(1-r)^2\cos(\beta-\alpha)+r(1-r)^2\cos(\beta-\alpha)\\
&\qquad-\frac{r^2}2\cos(2\beta-2\alpha)\\
&=(1-r^2)^2+\frac{1-\cos(2\beta-2\alpha)}2r^2&
\end{align}$$

Now, define $f(x)=(1-x^2)^2+kx^2$, where $0\leq k\leq 1$. We need to show that $f(x)\leq 1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$. Write
$$f(x)=\left(x^2-\frac{2-k}2\right)^2+1-\left(\frac{2-k}2\right)^2$$

Since $\sqrt{(2-k)/2}$ lies in the interval $[0,1]$, the function $f$ reaches its only minimum there, so we need only to check $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=k\leq 1$. This ends the proof.